# Async Lambda Function: Returning promise or sending responseURL does not terminate CloudFormation custom resource invocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have a lambda function invoked as a custom resource via a CloudFormation template. It Creates/Deletes AWS Connect instances. The API calls work fine but I cannot seem to terminate the custom resource invocation, so the last CF block remains CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. No matter what I return from the async function it just won't terminate the CF execution with a success.

I'm able to use a non-async handler successfully as in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html but I need to make multiple API calls and await completions, hence the need for async handler.

Below is the code in it's simplest form, though I've tried just about everything, including using callback and context (ie exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {...}), both of which should be unnecessary with an async handler. I've tried using cfn-response to directly send a response which seems to be ignored with async handlers. I've tried returning directly the promises with and without the await before them, tried returning variables containing various responseStatus and responseData, nothing seems to work.

```
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Parameters:
  IdentityManagementType:
    Description: The type of identity management for your Amazon Connect users.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: ["SAML", "CONNECT_MANAGED", "EXISTING_DIRECTORY"]
    Default: "SAML"
  InboundCallsEnabled:
    Description: Whether your contact center handles incoming contacts.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
    Default: true
  InstanceAlias:
    Description: The name for your instance.
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 62
  OutboundCallsEnabled:
    Description: Whether your contact center allows outbound calls.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
    Default: true
  DirectoryId:
    Description: Optional. The identifier for the directory, if using this type of Identity Management.
    Type: String
  ClientToken:
    Description: Optional. The idempotency token. Used for concurrent deployments
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 500
  Region:
    Description: Region to place the AWS Connect Instance
    Type: String
    Default: us-east-1
#Handler for optional values
Conditions:
  HasClientToken: !Not
    - !Equals
      - ""
      - !Ref ClientToken
  HasDirectoryId: !Not
    - !Equals
      - ""
      - !Ref DirectoryId

Resources:
  CreateConnectInstance:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-AWSConnectInstance"
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Description: Invoke a function to create an AWS Connect instance.
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Layers:
        - !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:node_sdk:1"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          IdentityManagementType:
            Ref: IdentityManagementType
          InboundCallsEnabled:
            Ref: InboundCallsEnabled
          InstanceAlias:
            Ref: InstanceAlias
          OutboundCallsEnabled:
            Ref: OutboundCallsEnabled
          Region:
            Ref: Region
          #Optional Values
          ClientToken: !If
            - HasClientToken
            - !Ref ClientToken
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
          DirectoryId: !If
            - HasClientToken
            - !Ref ClientToken
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      InlineCode: |
        var aws = require("aws-sdk");
        exports.handler = async function(event) {
            console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));
            var connect = new aws.Connect({region: event.ResourceProperties.Region});
            var isInboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.InboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
            var isOutboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.OutboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
            var createInstanceParams = {
                InboundCallsEnabled: isInboundCallsEnabled,
                OutboundCallsEnabled: isOutboundCallsEnabled,
                IdentityManagementType: process.env.IdentityManagementType,
                ClientToken: process.env.ClientToken,
                DirectoryId: process.env.DirectoryId,
                InstanceAlias: process.env.InstanceAlias
            };

            // Create AWS Connect instance using specified parameters
            if (event.RequestType == "Create") {
                return await connect.createInstance(createInstanceParams).promise();
                // I can store this in a variable and read the contents fine, but...
                // returning the promise does not terminate execution
            }
        };


  InvokeCreateConnectInstance:
    Type: Custom::CreateConnectInstance
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt CreateConnectInstance.Arn
      Region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
```

The documentaiton at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html explicitly states that you should be able to **return await apiCall.promise()** directly from any async function, exactly what I'm trying to do, such as

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

exports.handler = async function(event) {
  return s3.listBuckets().promise()
}
```

Why can't I return from my async function? Again the API calls are working, the Connect instances are created and deleted (though I've omitted the delete code for brevity), but CF just hangs hours and hours until eventually saying "Custom Resource failed to stabilize in expected time"

Here's the inline code by itself for readability:

```
        exports.handler = async function(event) {
            console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));
            var connect = new aws.Connect({region: event.ResourceProperties.Region});
            var isInboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.InboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
            var isOutboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.OutboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
            var createInstanceParams = {
                InboundCallsEnabled: isInboundCallsEnabled,
                OutboundCallsEnabled: isOutboundCallsEnabled,
                IdentityManagementType: process.env.IdentityManagementType,
                ClientToken: process.env.ClientToken,
                DirectoryId: process.env.DirectoryId,
                InstanceAlias: process.env.InstanceAlias
            };

            // Create AWS Connect instance using specified parameters
            if (event.RequestType == "Create") {
                return await connect.createInstance(createInstanceParams).promise();
                // I can store this in a variable and read the contents fine, but...
                // returning the promise does not terminate CF execution
            }
          };
```

UPDATE: I've implemented the sendResponse method exactly as shown in the AMI lookup example (the first link) and am sending exactly the correct structure for the response, it even includes the newly created connect instance ID in the data field:

```
{
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "Reason": "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2020/12/23/[$LATEST]6fef3553870b4fba90479a37b4360cee",
    "PhysicalResourceId": "2020/12/23/[$LATEST]6fef3553870b4fba90479a37b4360cee",
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:642608065726:stack/cr12/1105a290-4534-11eb-a6de-0a8534d05dcd",
    "RequestId": "2f7c3d9e-941f-402c-b739-d2d965288cfe",
    "LogicalResourceId": "InvokeCreateConnectInstance",
    "Data": {
        "InstanceId": "2ca7aa49-9b20-4feb-8073-5f23d63e4cbc"
    }
}
```

And STILL the custom resource will just not close in CloudFormation. I just don't understand why this is happening when I am returning the above to the event.responseURL. It's like specifying an async handler completely breaks the custom resource handler and prevents it from closing.

UPDATE: When I manually CURL the above response directly to the event.responseUrl the CF resource registers a success! WTF... I'm sending the exact same response as the lambda function is sending, and it accepts it from the CURL but not from my lambda function.

UPDATE: latest code including sendResponse, etc

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));
    var connect = new aws.Connect({region: event.ResourceProperties.Region});
    var isInboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.InboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
    var isOutboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.OutboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
    var createInstanceParams = {
        InboundCallsEnabled: isInboundCallsEnabled,
        OutboundCallsEnabled: isOutboundCallsEnabled,
        IdentityManagementType: process.env.IdentityManagementType,
        ClientToken: process.env.ClientToken,
        DirectoryId: process.env.DirectoryId,
        InstanceAlias: process.env.InstanceAlias
    };
    var responseStatus;
    var responseData = {};

    // Create Connect instance
    if (event.RequestType == "Create") {
        try {
            var createInstanceRequest = await connect.createInstance(createInstanceParams).promise();
            responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
            responseData = {"InstanceId": createInstanceRequest.Id};
        } catch (err) {
            responseStatus = "FAILED";
            responseData = {Error: "CreateInstance failed"};
            console.log(responseData.Error + ":\n", err);
        }
        sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);
        return;
    }

    // Look up the ID and call deleteInstance.
    if (event.RequestType == "Delete") {
        var instanceId;
        var listInstanceRequest = await connect.listInstances({}).promise();
        listInstanceRequest.InstanceSummaryList.forEach(instance => {
            if (instance.InstanceAlias == createInstanceParams.InstanceAlias) {
                instanceId = instance.Id;
            }
        });
        if (instanceId !== undefined) {
            try {
                var deleteInstanceRequest = await connect.deleteInstance({"InstanceId": instanceId}).promise();
                responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
                responseData = {"InstanceId": instanceId};
            } catch (err) {
                responseStatus = "FAILED";
                responseData = {Error: "DeleteInstance call failed"};
                console.log(responseData.Error + ":\n", err);
            }
        } else {
            responseStatus = "FAILED";
            responseData = {Error: "DeleteInstance failed; no match found"};
            console.log(responseData.Error);
        }
        sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);
        return;
    }
};

// Send response to the pre-signed S3 URL 
function sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData) {
    var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
        Status: responseStatus,
        Reason: "CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.logStreamName,
        PhysicalResourceId: context.logStreamName,
        StackId: event.StackId,
        RequestId: event.RequestId,
        LogicalResourceId: event.LogicalResourceId,
        Data: responseData
    });
    console.log("RESPONSE BODY:\n", responseBody);
    var https = require("https");
    var url = require("url");
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
    var options = {
        hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
        port: 443,
        path: parsedUrl.path,
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "",
            "content-length": responseBody.length
        }
    };
    console.log("SENDING RESPONSE...\n");
    var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
        console.log("STATUS: " + response.statusCode);
        console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
        context.done();
    });
    request.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("sendResponse Error:" + error);
        // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
        context.done();
    });
    // write data to request body
    request.write(responseBody);
    request.end();
}
```

Been at this for two days now :(

PS in the logs the "RESPONSE BODY" is shown as expected like I copied above, and log shows the "SENDING RESPONSE" but does **not** get to the the "STATUS: " and "HEADERS: " portion of the request.https() call, which makes me think something with async interferes with this call... IDK

Answer (score 17):

This one was really tricky but finally have everything figured out. I had to make the sendResponse function asynchronous by adding a promise to it, awaiting that promise and returning it. This allowed me to ultimately call "return await sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);" and finally everything is working, both create and delete operations are successful and the CloudFormation custom resource completes as expected. Phew. Posting code here in hopes that others will benefit from it.

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));
    var connect = new aws.Connect({region: event.ResourceProperties.Region});
    var isInboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.InboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
    var isOutboundCallsEnabled = (process.env.OutboundCallsEnabled == 'true');
    var createInstanceParams = {
        InboundCallsEnabled: isInboundCallsEnabled,
        OutboundCallsEnabled: isOutboundCallsEnabled,
        IdentityManagementType: process.env.IdentityManagementType,
        ClientToken: process.env.ClientToken,
        DirectoryId: process.env.DirectoryId,
        InstanceAlias: process.env.InstanceAlias
    };
    var responseStatus;
    var responseData = {};
    if (event.RequestType == "Create") {
        try {
            var createInstanceRequest = await connect.createInstance(createInstanceParams).promise();
            responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
            responseData = {"InstanceId": createInstanceRequest.Id};
        } catch (err) {
            responseStatus = "FAILED";
            responseData = {Error: "CreateInstance failed"};
            console.log(responseData.Error + ":\n", err);
        }
        return await sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);
    }

    if (event.RequestType == "Delete") {
        var instanceId;
        var listInstanceRequest = await connect.listInstances({}).promise();
        listInstanceRequest.InstanceSummaryList.forEach(instance => {
            if (instance.InstanceAlias == createInstanceParams.InstanceAlias) {
                instanceId = instance.Id;
            }
        });
        if (instanceId !== undefined) {
            try {
                var deleteInstanceRequest = await connect.deleteInstance({"InstanceId": instanceId}).promise();
                responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
                responseData = {"InstanceId": instanceId};
            } catch (err) {
                responseStatus = "FAILED";
                responseData = {Error: "DeleteInstance call failed"};
                console.log(responseData.Error + ":\n", err);
            }
        } else {
            responseStatus = "FAILED";
            responseData = {Error: "DeleteInstance failed; no match found"};
            console.log(responseData.Error);
        }
        return await sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);
    }
};

async function sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData) {
    let responsePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
            Status: responseStatus,
            Reason: "CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.logStreamName,
            PhysicalResourceId: context.logStreamName,
            StackId: event.StackId,
            RequestId: event.RequestId,
            LogicalResourceId: event.LogicalResourceId,
            Data: responseData
        });
        console.log("RESPONSE BODY:\n", responseBody);
        var https = require("https");
        var url = require("url");
        var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
        var options = {
            hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
            port: 443,
            path: parsedUrl.path,
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "",
                "content-length": responseBody.length
            }
        };
        console.log("SENDING RESPONSE...\n");
        var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
            console.log("STATUS: " + response.statusCode);
            console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
            context.done();
        });
        request.on("error", function(error) {
            console.log("sendResponse Error:" + error);
            reject(error);
            context.done();
        });
        request.write(responseBody);
        request.end();
    });
    return await responsePromise;
}
```

Comment: IMHO AWS should post documentation for how to return requests from custom resources with asynchronous handlers as it currently only covers synchronous cases. I will definitely be using this as a model for future custom resources that require async.

Comment: Thanks for providing this complete example and your thought process on working it through.

Comment: This is very strange. It looks like AWS have incorrectly implemented `cfn-response` to fire off the HTTPS request without waiting for a response. Why this works for sync Lambdas and not for async Lambdas is a mystery, but perhaps async Lambdas are terminated earlier than sync Lambdas, thus preventing the HTTPS request from being sent out? Would be great if someone from AWS could investigate and comment and fix their implementation of `cfn-response` and associated documentation

Comment: Thanks for this answer, surprised the AWS documentation is so bad.

Comment: You don't need to `await` on the promise - you can just not define the function as `async` and just return the response - as @chaserb did.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a variant on the OP's answer for those using the "ZipFile" option in the ["Code" property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html) of an [AWS::Lambda::Function resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) in CloudFormation. The advantage of the ZipFile approach is that in addition permitting Lambda code inlined into the CF template, it also automatically bundles a "cfn-response.js" function very similar to the "async function sendResponse" in the OP's answer. With the insight gained from the OP's answer regarding a promised response (thank you, I was stuck and perplexed), this is how I incorporated the cfn-response function as an await-able Promise to signal CF after my asynchronous AWS API calls (omitted for brevity) were complete:

```
CreateSnapshotFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
        Runtime: nodejs12.x
        Handler: index.handler
        Timeout: 900 # 15 mins
        Code:
            ZipFile: !Sub |
                const resp = require('cfn-response');
                const aws = require('aws-sdk');
                const cf = new aws.CloudFormation({apiVersion: '2010-05-15'});
                const rds = new aws.RDS({apiVersion: '2014-10-31'});

                exports.handler = async function(evt, ctx) {
                    if (evt.RequestType == "Create") {
                        try {
                            // Query the given CF stack, determine its database
                            // identifier, create a snapshot of the database,
                            // and await an "available" status for the snapshot
                            let stack = await getStack(stackNameSrc);
                            let srcSnap = await createSnapshot(stack);
                            let pollFn = () => describeSnapshot(srcSnap.DBSnapshot.DBSnapshotIdentifier);
                            let continueFn = snap => snap.DBSnapshots[0].Status !== 'available';
                            await poll(pollFn, continueFn, 10, 89); // timeout after 14 min, 50 sec

                            // Send response to CF
                            await send(evt, ctx, resp.SUCCESS, {
                                SnapshotId: srcSnap.DBSnapshot.DBSnapshotIdentifier,
                                UpgradeRequired: upgradeRequired
                            });
                        } catch(err) {
                            await send(evt, ctx, resp.FAILED, { ErrorMessage: err } );
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Send success to CF for delete and update requests
                        await send(evt, ctx, resp.SUCCESS, {});
                    }
                };

                function send(evt, ctx, status, data) {
                    return new Promise(() => { resp.send(evt, ctx, status, data) });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and Delete S3 Object by CFN Custom Resource

```
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
    CustomResourceLambdaExecutionRole:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                          Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
                      Action:
                          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            ManagedPolicyArns:
              - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: CustomS3Access
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: 2012-10-17
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - logs:CreateLogGroup
                                - logs:CreateLogStream
                                - logs:PutLogEvents
                            Resource: '*'
                - PolicyName: S3Policy
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: 2012-10-17
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - s3:List*
                                - s3:DeleteObject
                            Resource: '*'

    CustomResourceLambdaFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:    
            InlineCode: |
                const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
                const S3Client = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region:  "us-east-1"});

                exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
                    const { RequestType, ResourceProperties  } = event;

                    let responseData = {};
                    let noOfObjects;
                    responseData['Message'] = "Defaut setting";
                    const bucketParams = { Bucket: ResourceProperties.s3bucketName };

                    if(RequestType == 'Create'){
                        responseData['Message'] = "Resource creation successful!";
                    }
                    else if(RequestType == 'Update'){
                        responseData['Message'] = "Resource update successful!";
                    }
                    else if(RequestType == 'Delete'){
                        const data = await S3Client.listObjects(bucketParams).promise()

                        noOfObjects = data.Contents;                            
                        for (let i = 0; i < noOfObjects.length; i++) {
                            const res = await S3Client.deleteObject({
                                    Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket,
                                    Key: noOfObjects[i].Key,
                                    }).promise()
                        };
                        responseData['Message'] = "Resource deletion successful!"
                        return await sendResponse(event, context, "SUCCESS", responseData)
                      }
                      return await sendResponse(event, context, "SUCCESS", responseData);                      
                };

                async function sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData) {
                    let responsePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
                            Status: responseStatus,
                            Reason: "CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.logStreamName,
                            PhysicalResourceId: context.logStreamName,
                            StackId: event.StackId,
                            RequestId: event.RequestId,
                            LogicalResourceId: event.LogicalResourceId,
                            Data: responseData
                        });
                        console.log("RESPONSE BODY:\n", responseBody);
                        var https = require("https");
                        var url = require("url");
                        var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
                        var options = {
                            hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
                            port: 443,
                            path: parsedUrl.path,
                            method: "PUT",
                            headers: {
                                "content-type": "",
                                "content-length": responseBody.length
                            }
                        };
                        console.log("SENDING RESPONSE...\n");
                        var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
                            console.log("STATUS: " + response.statusCode);
                            console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
                            resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
                            context.done();
                        });
                        request.on("error", function(error) {
                            console.log("sendResponse Error:" + error);
                            reject(error);
                            context.done();
                        });
                        request.write(responseBody);
                        request.end();
                    });
                    return await responsePromise;
                }

            Timeout: 20
            Handler: index.handler
            Runtime: nodejs12.x    
            Role: !GetAtt CustomResourceLambdaExecutionRole.Arn

    S3Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: yaya-test-v50final

    CustomResource:
      Type: Custom::CustomResource
      Properties:
          ServiceToken: !GetAtt CustomResourceLambdaFunction.Arn
          s3bucketName: !Ref S3Bucket
```

Comment: In order to improve this answer (and gain some up votes), can you provide some explanation as to why this solution works, or is different to previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

This simplest thing to do is to use the AWS Lambda runtime's `cfn-response` module and not export your handler as an `async` function.

When your function is `async`, the AWS Lambda runtime will rely on your handler's `Promise` resolving (or rejecting) to signal the end of the execution, and if you mess that up - you'd get an early or late termination.

OTOH, if your handler is not `async`, the AWS Lambda will rely on the context being completed in "legacy" way, which the built-in `cfn-response` module knows how to do.

If you want to write `async` function to do all the actual functionality - that's not a problem, just call them and handle the `Promise` they return:

```
const response = require('./cfn-response');
const actual = async function(param) {
  // stuff to be done using await
};
exports.handler = function(ev,ctx) {
  actual("foo")
  .then(data => response.send(ev, ctx, response.SUCCESS, data))
  .catch(err => response.send(ev, ctx, response.FAILED, { Error: "Error occured " + err }));
};
```

Note that the handler doesn't return anything - it it will return something synchronously - that will end the runtime.

If you really really want to write an `async` handler, then you can make sure that the built-in `cfn-response` returns a promise (the one from the `nodejs20.x` does, I'm not sure about earlier ones) or use one of the external `async` ones (as those presented here) and `await` on their `send()` method - but I think the above way is simpler.

BTW - if you want to bundle a local `async` supporting `cfn-response` module because the AWS Lambda runtime you use has an old implementation (not that should be the case as all `nodejs` runtimes older than `nodejs20.x` are deprecated), you can get a copy of the latest `cfn-response` module from the AWS Lambda runtime by creating a function that uses the latest runtime, and runs this code:

```js
try {
console.log("cfn-response: ", fs.readFileSync("./cfn-response.js").toString('utf8'));
} catch (e) {}
```

this will output to the log, the code of the built-in `cfn-response` module, that you can copy and deploy into your lambda function. I believe the licensing for this code will not allow me to post it publicly, so I obviously didn't do that :-D.